# The Badness of Badboxes

Tags: formatting

On this forum, I have had many of the more experienced users tell me to tweak my format so that I eliminate badboxes.  I do not see the point of nitpicking my LaTeX code to eliminate badboxes.  I have many badboxes in all of my documents and they compile just fine.  So, my question is what is so bad about badboxes?

Comment: Is this about what you post on the main site, or in your TeX document as output?

Comment: @Werner I am referring to both.

Comment: How do people "eliminate badboxes in your format" on the main site? Please provide a link, since it is not very clear.

Comment: In my point of view this is a question for TeX.SX, not for Meta.TeX.SX

Comment: @Werner I have clarified the question.